# Getting the id of the <Select> from event.target in a MUI Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, onchange

I'm a beginner in React, but not to programming. I'm writing up a form, and some of the examples I've seen written have an onChange handler for every single input, but that seemed to violate DRY principles, so I wrote a generic handler for all Text inputs.

```
const handleTextInputChange = (event) => {
    dispatch(
        formActions.set({ key: event.target.id, value: event.target.value })
    );
};
```

Because I'm using a Redux store that has keys that are the same as the ID of my inputs, this works great.

However, I'm trying to do the same with my Select inputs. When I try to access the event, I can't seem to get the id of the select. I can get the value of the selected option through event.target.value, but event.currentTarget returns undefined, and I'm not sure if this is a material-ui failing, or I'm just not doing it right. Any ideas? Is there another way I can pass the id of the Select onto the dispatch/handler?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

const BasicInputs = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const state = useSelector((state) => state.form);

    const handleTextInputChange = (event) => {
        dispatch(
            formActions.set({ key: event.target.id, value: event.target.value })
        );
    };

    const handleSpendingPlanChange = (event) => {
        console.log("Event:", event.target);
        dispatch(
            formActions.set({ key: "spendingPlan", value: event.target.value })
        );
    };

return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="textField">
                    Retirement Start Year
                </InputLabel>
                <OutlinedInput
                    id="textField"
                    label="Test Text Field"
                    defaultValue="Stuff"
                    onChange={handleTextInputChange}
                />
            </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                <InputLabel id="spending-plan-label">Spending Plan</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="spending-plan-label"
                    id="spendingPlan"
                    value={state.spendingPlan}
                    label="Spending Plan"
                    onChange={handleSpendingPlanChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={"inflation-adjusted"}>Inflation Adjusted</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    );
};

export default BasicInputs;
```

Comment: If you're trying to keep it as DRY as possible, it may be better to use the componenet's name and `event.target.name` For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cookies-d5xq5x?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @SteveGomez that absolutely works, but why? Is it a bug in the MUI components that ID gets lost along the way?

Comment: @LaurenBoland It isn't a bug. Unless you use `NativeSelect`, the `onChange` event has to be [constructed in Material-UI](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.13.4/packages/mui-material/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L297) in response to a click event on a `MenuItem`. If the original `event` were passed to you, the `id` would be for the clicked `MenuItem` rather than the select.

Comment: Right, but in a standard HTML Select, you can get the id of the select from event.currentTarget, but currentTarget is null for these Material-UI constructed Select's.  It just seems like an expected behavior (based on vanilla HTML/JS) that isn't working.

Thanks for all of the clarification though!